# How to determine which process owns a toplevel window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, process, window

In Windows XP (and perhaps up to Windows 7) in *Task Manager* there was a *Windows* tab where I could right-click an entry for an unidentified message box and then switch to the process which owns that window.

In Windows 10 however, Task Manager has drastically changed. I no longer find anything resembling the Windows tab, so can't seem to do the same procedure I could in Windows XP.

Is the functionality lost? If yes, what stock utility can be used in Windows 10 to determine which process owns a particular toplevel window?

Comment: Process Explorer - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer - you can drag the cross-hairs on to the window and it will highlight the process.

Comment: The [tab you're remembering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBYM9.png) was the *Applications* tab. And yes, it was present in the Windows 7 Task Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still possible in Windows 10 (explained below), but a more robust version of this ability is available in Microsoft's freely available [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) utility. By "more robust" I mean it can identify the process associated with *any* visible on-screen element, right down to individual icons displayed in the System Tray. Here's how:

### Using Process Explorer

1. Run Process Explorer (As Admin if the target process is likely to be running outside the current user's security context).
2. Click and drag the **Find Window's Process** tool from the toolbar to the window or GUI element in question. The tool looks like this: [image]
3. Process Explorer will highlight in its list the process that owns the window:

[image]

---

### The old-fashion way: Windows 10 Task Manager

1. Start Task Manager.
2. If necessary, switch to the Detailed view by clicking **More details** at the bottom.
3. On the *Processes* tab right-click an application and click **Go to details**.
   [image]
4. You'll be taken to the *Details* tab where the owning process will be highlighted.
   [image]